# how to install lamp/xampp server on beaglebone black

Tags: php, apache, xampp, lamp, beagleboneblack

i am unable to install lamp or xampp server on my BBB.when i typed

sudo apt-get install apache2

it says "sudo :command not found"

opkg install php php-cgi php-cli
opkg install lighttpd lighttpd-module-fastcgi
opkg install mysql5

also the above commands do not work.The error says "unknown package ..."

Basically i am trying to develop a webserver which over the internet can be accessed to control hardware interfaced to BBB.

is there any way to solve this problem.I am using only usb connection to connect BBB using putty.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78676/opkg-cant-find-apache

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Angstrom Distribution apache may not work. It freezes in between installation. Try upgrading to Ubuntu or Debian. Previous versions of BBB had very low memory (2GB) of which 1.5GB was taken by the OS. So try expanding it using a micro-SD card.

And it is a good practice to always update and upgrade your OS before installing any software.

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```